# How to make MySQL / Sequelize query join

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have 2 models, User and Message, and an index and I'm looking to create a get request statement that would return all messages where ....

- I (sender_id) sent the user messages and the other user (receiver_id)received.
- The other user (sender_id) sent the message and I (receiver_id) received it.

and then somehow join those together so that I can display a chain of messages by created_at

but I'm new to all of this and struggling to figure this out.

```
var User = db.seq.define('User',{
    id: {type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    username: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING},
    email: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING},
    password: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING},

});

var Message= db.seq.define('Message',{
    id: {type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    receiver_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    message_text: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING},

});

User.hasMany(Message, {
    foreignKey: 'sender_id'
});

Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'sender_id'
});
```

Basically I'm looking to setup something like this... but I'm sure I'm doing this all wrong and probably should use sequelize literal but struggling with that as well

```
  Message.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        // grab user id from the session data
        { receiver_id: req.session.user_id },
        { sender_id: req.params.id },
      ],
      [Op.or]: [
        // grab user id from the session data
        { receiver_id: req.params.id },
        { sender_id: req.session.user_id },
      ],
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'message_text', 'created_at'],
    // display newest messages first
    order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
      },
    ],
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

First I don't see `sender_id` field definition in the `Message` model though I see `receiver_id` and they both should be explicitly defined or just mentioned in associations or be implicitly named by Sequelize if omitted in associations.
Second, you definitely need one more association from `Message` to `User` to get a receiver as a user for a certain message (if you want it of course). In the case you want it you need to indicate aliases for both associations to distinguish sender and receiver users:

```js
Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'sender_id'
    as: 'Sender'
});
Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'receiver_id'
    as: 'Receiver'
});
```

The same goes for other end associations as well:

```js
User.hasMany(Message, {
    foreignKey: 'sender_id',
    as: 'SentMessages'
});
User.hasMany(Message, {
    foreignKey: 'receiver_id',
    as: 'ReceivedMessages'
});
```

Third, you need to correct conditions in the `where` option according to what you described:

```js
Message.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
         // these two conditions will be joined by AND
         // grab user id from the session data
         receiver_id: req.session.user_id,
         sender_id: req.params.id
        },
        {
          // these two conditions will be joined by AND
          // grab user id from the session data
          receiver_id: req.params.id,
          sender_id: req.session.user_id
        },
      ],
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'message_text', 'created_at'],
    // display newest messages first
    order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        // don't forget to indicate a certain alias depending on what user you wish to get here
        as: 'Sender'
      },
    ],
  })
```

Comment: thanks for chiming in, I appreciate any understand I can get.

So I did have the relationship/association defined with a foreign key which I thought would be used so there wouldn't be any need to re-create in the model-- is this not correct?


User.hasMany(Message, {
    foreignKey: 'sender_id'
});

Message.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'sender_id'
});

Comment: If you only need a sender as a user object then it looks good